How can I use hair curves with Physics like wind
I made my hair using the new hair assets and curves. Now I want to run some quick simulations to see how they work in my system. How can I achieve this/ Is it possible with hair curves?
If not, is there an alternative to making hair for simulation that is not so PC demanding?

